# Unable to route the yii2 application in cpanel

Tags: php, yii2, cpanel, yii2-advanced-app

I have uploaded my yii2 project to my `cpanel`. My `url` with alias is `xyz.com`. Below is my index and ht access file

**Index.html**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    $uri = 'https://';
} else {
    $uri = 'http://';
}
$uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
header('Location: '.$uri.'/backend/dashboard/');
exit;
?>
Something is wrong :-(
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**Structure**

[image]

[image]

On my local machine. The URL is `localhost/backend/web`. On my production server, the `URL` i want to access is `xyz.com`. But all I am able to access is `xyz.com/backend/web`.

If I hit the URL `xyz.com` I am getting the `Something is wrong :-(` message.

If I delete the `index.html` file then I am getting the `This page isn’t working` message.

How can I access it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ backend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: at which line i have to add it ?

Comment: top level htaccess `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ backend/web/$1 [L] `